# Can't link building C++ application with pqxx library

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, c++

I had to re-install my operating system and I switched from Ubuntu 22.04 to Linux Mint 21.2. I installed PostgreSQL 16 from the postgres repository. It seems to work fine.

Then I downloaded [libpqxx 7.8.1](https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx/releases/tag/7.8.1), built it and installed it. That seemed to work too. The libraries are in `/usr/local/lib/`.

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/
total 19436
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19887870 Dec 14 10:28 libpqxx.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      885 Dec 14 10:28 libpqxx.la
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Dec 14 10:28 pkgconfig
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Jul 11 12:08 python3.10
```

This command is supposed to tell me where the linker is looking for its libraries, and it includes the correct directory.

```
$ ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu");
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu");
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu");
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64");
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib64");
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib64");
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib64");
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib");
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib");
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib");
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64");
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib");
```

It is all set up just like it was on my previous system, but with more recent versions. However, when I build the application using the same makefile, I get the following error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: db.o: in function `pqxx::internal::(anonymous namespace)::throw_for_encoding_error(char const*, char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long)':
db.cpp:(.text+0x20f): undefined reference to `pqxx::argument_error::argument_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::source_location)'
/usr/bin/ld: db.o: in function `pqxx::check_version()':
btc-db.cpp:(.text._ZN4pqxx13check_versionEv[_ZN4pqxx13check_versionEv]+0x31): undefined reference to `pqxx::internal::check_pqxx_version_7_8()'
/usr/bin/ld: app.o: in function `pqxx::internal::(anonymous namespace)::throw_for_encoding_error(char const*, char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long)':
app.cpp:(.text+0x20f): undefined reference to `pqxx::argument_error::argument_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::source_location)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:2: app] Error 1
```

What can I do to get this to link?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. What helped me, choose one of variant:

1. Reduce c++ version to 17 in project you build
2. Increase c++ version of pqxx when building to 20